# How to allow scroll x using keyboard arrows on hover?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to scroll horizontally using keyboard arrows when hovering on `div`.

I also tried to simulate a click

```
document.getElementById("demo").onmouseover = function() {this.click()};
```

But it's not working, is there another way?

codepen link: https://codepen.io/Muh-Ail/pen/NWyqrzJ?editors=0010

Comment: A proper [mre] of your issue belongs directly inside the question, not just dumped onto an external platform.

Comment: What is not working ? Maybe this is the question you need to ask yourself. Then after you figured what precisely isn't working, you should clarify your question. And what CBroe said too. And you should give us *all* the code related to your question.